# Variadic Template function returns a std::tuple with the same template argument types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have this kind of functions to parse binary data stream from network. It works well:

```
template<typename... Args>
inline void Func(char* data) {
    cout << "unknown" << endl;
}

template<>
inline void Func<int, std::string>(char* data) {
    int a = *(int*)data;
    cout << a << endl;
}

inline void test() {
    char p[100];
    int a = 99;
    memcpy(p, &a, sizeof(a));
    Func<int, int>(p);
    Func<int, std::string>(p);
}
```

Further more, I not only want to output the parsed values, I also want to return them with a tuple. Something like this,

```
template<typename... Args>
inline std::tuple<typename... Args> FuncTuple(char* data) {
    cout << "unknown" << endl;
}

template<>
inline std::tuple<int, std::string> FuncTuple<int, std::string>(char* data) {
    std::tuple<int, std::string> t;
    std::get<0>(t)=*(int*)data;
    return t;
}
```

However, it doesn't work because the compiler doesn't recognize `std::tuple<typename... Args>`. How do I write it?

Comment: Try `std::tuple<Args...>` instead.

Comment: I just realize, that would make FuncTuple returning different types, it wouldn't work. I think passing out the result with a reference argument would do.

Comment: I think it twice, returning a vector<std::variant> would be better.

Comment: @Zhang you can't use `std::variant` without specifying template arguments for every type it holds. For instance: `std::vector<std::variant<int, std::string>>`. Your suggestion to return a `std::tuple` by reference parameter will work, and it has the benefit that template argument deduction can be used at the call site, so you don't have to pass template arguments to the function explicitly, eg: `template<> inline std::tuple<int, std::string> FuncTuple<int, std::string>(char* data, std::tuple<int, std::string> &t) { ... }` ... `char p[100]; ... std::tuple<int, std::string> t; FuncTuple(p, t);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I had thought std::variant is like QVariant -- doesn't need template arguments :D

Comment: @Zhang nope. `QVariant` is not a template class, it holds only a specific set of types that Qt defines for it. `std::variant`, on the other hand, is a more generic template class, and it can hold whatever types you want it to hold, but you have to specify those types explicitly.  Otherwise, use `std::any` instead, which is not a template class (but is also much harder to use than `std::variant`).